# Multi-tier architecture: Angular, Node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, architecture, multi-tier

I'm using `angular7`, `Node.js` and `mySQL`to create a platform, each one of them runs on a seperate port and I'm only using HTTP protocol , I'm really confused if it's a 3 tier architecture `(client, web server, DB)` or 4 tier architecture `(client, web server, application server, DB)`

Comment: it seems 4 tier to me but usually, multi-tier architecture involves separate platform/system for each tier instead of on platform/system with different port.